# "Uncurrying" an instance method in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming, delegates, currying

Can you create a delegate of an instance method without specifying the instance at creation time?  In other words, can you create a "static" delegate that takes as it's first parameter the instance the method should be called on?

For example, how can I construct the following delegate using reflection?

```
Func<int, string> = i=>i.ToString();
```

I'm aware of the fact that I can use methodInfo.Invoke, but this is slower, and does not check for type-correctness until it is called.

When you have the `MethodInfo` of a particular *static* method, it is possible to construct a delegate using `Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, methodInfo)`, and all parameters of the static method remain free.

As Jon Skeet pointed out, you can simply apply the same to make an open delegate of an instance method if the method is non-virtual on a reference type.  Deciding which method to call on a virtual method is tricky, so that's no so trivial, and value-types look like they don't work at all.

For value types, `CreateDelegate` exhibits really weird behavior:

```
var func37 = (Func<CultureInfo,string>)(37.ToString);
var toStringMethod = typeof(int).GetMethod("ToString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] {typeof(CultureInfo) }, null);
var func42 = (Func<CultureInfo,string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<CultureInfo,string>), 42, toStringMethod,true);
Console.WriteLine( object.ReferenceEquals(func37.Method,func42.Method)); //true
Console.WriteLine(func37.Target);//37
Console.WriteLine(func42.Target);//42
Console.WriteLine(func37(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));//37
Console.WriteLine(func42(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));//-201040128... WTF?
```

Calling `CreateDelegate` with `null` as the target object throws a binding exception if the instance method belonged to a value type (this works for reference types).

*Some follow-up years later:* The incorrectly-bound target that caused `func42(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` to return `"-201040128"` instead of `"42"` in my example was memory corruption that could have allowed remote code execution ([cve-2010-1898](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2010-1898)); this was fixed in 2010 in the [ms10-060](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2010/ms10-060) security update.  Current frameworks correctly print 42!  That doesn't make answering this question any easier, but explains the particularly weird behavior in the example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've actually chosen a particularly tricky example, for two reasons:

- ToString() is a virtual method inherited from `object` but overridden in `Int32`.
- `int` is a value type, and there are weird rules with `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` when it comes to value types and instance methods - basically the first effective parameter becomes `ref int` rather than `int`

However, here's an example for `String.ToUpper`, which doesn't have either of those problems:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod
            ("ToUpper", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
             null, new Type[]{}, null);

        Func<string, string> func = (Func<string, string>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, string>),
                                    null,
                                    method);

        string x = func("hello");

        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

If that's good enough for you, great... if you really want `int.ToString`, I'll have to try a bit harder :)

Here's an example for a value type, using a new delegate type which takes its first parameter by reference:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public struct Foo
{
    readonly string value;

    public Foo(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public string DemoMethod()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

class Test
{
    delegate TResult RefFunc<TArg, TResult>(ref TArg arg);

    static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Foo).GetMethod
            ("DemoMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
             null, new Type[]{}, null);
        RefFunc<Foo, string> func = (RefFunc<Foo, string>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RefFunc<Foo, string>),
                                    null,
                                    method);

        Foo y = new Foo("hello");
        string x = func(ref y);

        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where it becomes clear that C# still has room to grow as a functional language. Treating functions as first class citizens still is still not as seamless as we may like. Is there any way to exploit the dynamic features in C#4 to make this sort of thing any easier?

Comment: @LBushkin: I don't think so. In fact, dynamic typing and lambdas don't go terribly well together to start with - the compiler has to know what type to convert the lambda expression to at compile time.

Comment: I *had* been testing on int.ToString, but for actual use I suppose I could do without virtual methods - though not without structs. Anyhow, thanks for the heads-up, I had overlooked the complexity of virtual methods, and the error message isn't exactly informative...

Comment: Wow, you're quick ;-).  I'm not sure it's possible - I tried looking through MethodInfo.Invoke with reflector to see if it treats structs specially, but it ends up in native code (some CLR stub, no doubt).

Comment: Looks like int is a special case?  Code similar to your doesn't work for an int.  Weird.  Not that it's undoable to make workarounds for builtin types, but it's odd.

Comment: @Eamon: What method were you trying to use? It would have to be a non-virtual instance method, I suspect. It all gets somewhat complex...

Comment: Is there any page where your second bullet point ("weird rules") is documented? I can't find any place where the fact that the first parameter becomes passed by reference except this answer.

Comment: @Lazlo: I'm not sure - I don't remember details myself, I'm afraid.

Comment: 10 years later... I'm guessing the language is still lacking in this area? I need to bind delegate to property getter for struct type unknown at compile time. :(  Is it even possible?

Comment: @JamesHoux: It's *possible* that some of the `ref` changes in C# 7 would help, but I'm not sure. It might be best to ask a new question with your specific example and what you've tried.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually...it looks like I was completely confused.  I thought your suggestion of "RefFunc<>" was strictly hypothetical. You were, in fact saying that RefFunc is real! I tried RefFunc<> and compiler tells me its an unknown type!  Ctrl+. shows no fixes. How do I get to use RefFunc<>?

Comment: @JamesHoux: It's a delegate type declared in the `Test` class.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Oh my. I completely missed that. I think I'm developing code blindness or something. LOL Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but may be [Open delegates](http://tips.x-tensive.com/2008/10/open-delegates_8670.html) can help you.

Upd: Follow this [link](http://www.google.com/search?q=.NET+tips+tricks+Open+delegates), if first one don't works.

Comment: That link leads to a 404 page - maybe you mistyped?

Comment: Weird, clicking on the link brings me to a 404 page, refreshing the page brings up the same 404 - But pressing enter in the url bar then (i.e. removing the referer) brings up the page.  Some Browser/Server bug, apparently (FF3.5.1 only - chrome works fine).  Anyhow, found the page now ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Eamon. It's first time I see this bug, usually blogger links work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Lambdas to get a "somewhat" compiled static wrapper for your instance method.

The sample below isn't exactly blazingly fast, yet it should be significantly faster than any plain dynamic invoke.

The output

```
100000 iterations took 4 ms 
1000000 iterations took 18 ms 
10000000 iterations took 184 ms
```

The code

```
class Program
{

   public sealed class Test
   {
      public String Data { get; set; }
      public override string ToString()
      {
         return Data;
      }
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      TestRun(100000);
      TestRun(1000000);
      TestRun(10000000);
   }

   private static void TestRun(int iterations)
   {
      var toString = typeof(Test).GetMethod("ToString",
                                            BindingFlags.Instance
                                            | BindingFlags.Public,
                                            null,
                                            Type.EmptyTypes,
                                            null);
      var call = GetCall<Test, String>(toString);
      var tests
         = (from i in Enumerable.Range(1, iterations)
            select new Test { Data = "..." + i }).ToList();

      var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      tests.ForEach(i => call(i));
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine("{0} iterations took {1} ms", iterations, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
   }

   private static Func<T, M> GetCall<T, M>(MethodInfo methodInfo)
   {
      var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "input");
      MethodCallExpression member = Expression.Call(input, methodInfo);
      var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, M>>(member, input);

      return lambda.Compile();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The goog way maybe can be useing the "dynamic" type in .NET 4.0. However the Delegate need the instance (for non-static methods). The problems is more complex then lokks at first time because of polymorfism etc...