# Is it a bug that Delegate.CreateDelegate cannot bind to struct member overrides?

Tags: c#, delegates

After following the answer on this I discovered that I have to use a `ref` parameter to call instance method on structs.
[How can I create an open Delegate from a struct's instance method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326736/how-can-i-create-an-open-delegate-from-a-structs-instance-method/4327011#4327011)

I cannot seem to bind to method overrides like explicit interface implementations (to avoid the boxing penalty associated, (which are really overrides as far as the IL is concerned)),
Here is a bug report saying that in a future version of .NET, we can bind to interface members found on a struct:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/574959/cannot-create-open-instance-delegate-for-value-types-methods-which-implement-an-interface?wa=wsignin1.0#details

But even trying to bind to members like `Equals`,`GetHashCode`,or `ToString` leads to errors 
e.g.

```
public struct A
{
     public override int GetHashCode(){/*implementation goes here*/}
}
delegate TRet FuncByRef<TStruct,TRet>(ref TStruct) where TStruct:struct
```

...

```
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(FuncByRef<A,int>),typeof(A).GetMethod("GetHashCode"));
```

will fail with the exception "Error binding to target method".

Comment: Re the boxing overhead / virtual; note that the interface treatment is only available with the constrained opcode, usually via a generic constraint. The handling of the virtual methods depends on whether it has been overridden (then it can use static-call) or not (virtual-call).

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I'm not sure if this is correct I can call `Int32.ToInt64(null)` inside an expression tree for instance and there doesn't appear to be any boxing. As the method performs faster than if I first cast it to `IConvertible`

Answer (score 0):

How about letting the compiler worry about it, i.e.

```
public static string SomeHelper(A obj) {
    return obj.SomeMethod();
}
```

Then bind instead to "SomeHelper". This could also be a generic method of needed, where it will use the magic "constrained" opcode.

This is also similar to

```
Func<A string> func = obj => obj.SomeMethod();
```

If you are usig reflection to get the method you might try DynamicMethod.

Comment: While I can create the indirection myself certainly, I was wondering why the helper method cannot figure this out. I can certainly write a dynamic method to invoke on an by-ref int parameter it's `GetHashCode` method, but why cannot I use the built in method that's supposed to handle this stuff?

Comment: @MichaelB - you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, upgrading to a later version of .net, namely 4.5 resolved the issue.