# Open instance delegates to value types

Tags: c#, delegates, clr

Delegate.CreateDelegate fails when I try to create open instance delegates to value type methods that implement interfaces. Because the instance method is on a value type, the first argument must be a ref, so let's define a general delegate type for this:

```
delegate T2 VF<T0, T1, T2>(ref T0 arg0, T1 arg1);
```

Now here's a program that succeeds in creating an open instance delegate to int.ToString(string), but fails to create an open instance delegate to int.Equals(int):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tos = typeof(int).GetMethod("ToString", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var tosopen = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                          typeof(VF<int, string, string>), null, tos);
        // success!

        var eq = typeof(int).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(int) });
        var eqopen = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                         typeof(VF<int, int, bool>), null, eq);
        // previous line fails with "Error binding to target method"
    }
}
```

This seems to be due to the fact that int.Equals(int) implements `IEquatable<int>`. Note that  the following *does* work:

```
var x = typeof(IEquatable<int>).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(int) });
var xopen = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                typeof(Func<IEquatable<int>, int, bool>), null, x);
xopen(1,1); // returns true
```

But this isn't exactly what I want, since this would seem to box any integers passed as the first argument. I also don't want to compare any `IEquatable<int>`, I want to specifically call the method to compare two ints.

Any thoughts on what's wrong here?

A Microsoft Connect bug was [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326917/144873) that seems directly related, but that link no longer works for me, and I can't find that bug by searching.

Edit: note that the same problem occurs when trying to create open instance delegates to overridden methods, so it's not just interface methods.

Comment: This small diffrerence between codes causes any trouble?: new`Type`[] { typeof(string) }

Comment: Did you notice that the `IEquatable` test works only with `Func` but not with `VF`?

Comment: VF doesn't work because it accepts a ref parameter as the first argument. An open instance delegate's first parameter must be an "address referencing the object", but a "ref IEquatable<int>" is an "address to an address referencing an object".

Comment: Did you try the override `var eqopen = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(VF<int, int, bool>), eq);` instead (without the `null`)?  Both seem to compile fine for me, but maybe it doesn't like `null` without the boxing.

Comment: Compilation usually works with open instance delegates because it's a runtime cast, so they typically fail at runtime. The overload with null is the most general one, and it supports creating open instance delegates, and you can see in the docs they pass in null: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This ran as part of a time test, hope it helps.

```
    public delegate Boolean RefFunc<T>(ref T arg1, Object arg2);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double loops = 1e6;
        Random random = new Random();
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo m;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        Type type = typeof(double);

        double tmp;
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var deligates = new Dictionary<Type, RefFunc<double>>();
        RefFunc<double> d;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < loops; ii++)
        {
            if (!deligates.TryGetValue(type, out d))
            {
                m = type.GetMethod("Equals", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(Object) }, null);
                d = (RefFunc<double>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RefFunc<double>), null, m);
                deligates[typeof(double)] = d;
            }
            tmp = Convert.ToDouble(random.Next(0, 100));
            d(ref tmp, Convert.ToDouble(random.Next(0, 100)));
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Delegate " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Delegate " + (stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks / loops).ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Edit: Just noticed the original post's date, but it could still save others a lot of time.