# Cannot create delegate for methods on value types

Tags: c#, delegates, value-type

I'm trying to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` on the `ToString()` method.

It works perfectly fine on reference types, but fails on value types.

Here is my test code:

```
using System;

class ReferenceType { }

struct ValueType { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var referenceMethod = typeof(ReferenceType).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
        var referenceDelegate = (Func<ReferenceType, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<ReferenceType, string>), referenceMethod);

        var valueMethod = typeof(ValueType).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
        var valueDelegate = (Func<ValueType, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<ValueType, string>), valueMethod);

        Console.WriteLine(referenceDelegate.Invoke(new ReferenceType()));
        Console.WriteLine(valueDelegate.Invoke(new ValueType()));
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to create `valueDelegate`, I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'

Yet, `ValueType.ToString()` exists and matches the signature of `Func<ValueType, String>`.

Replacing `ValueType` with any primitive type (e.g. `int`) does the same thing.

Is there any reason to this limitation?

How can I create the delegate?

Edit: After furthre testing, it seems that any method (not just `ToString`) fails on the value type, for example:

```
using System;

class ReferenceType
{
    public string Test() { return "Test"; }
}

struct ValueType
{
    public string Test() { return "Test"; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var referenceMethod = typeof(ReferenceType).GetMethod("Test", Type.EmptyTypes);
        var referenceDelegate = (Func<ReferenceType, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<ReferenceType, string>), referenceMethod);

        var valueMethod = typeof(ValueType).GetMethod("Test", Type.EmptyTypes);
        var valueDelegate = (Func<ValueType, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<ValueType, string>), valueMethod);

        Console.WriteLine(referenceDelegate.Invoke(new ReferenceType()));
        Console.WriteLine(valueDelegate.Invoke(new ValueType()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer related to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1212396/1992137

Comment: Good catch, I'll vote to close as duplicate.