# List of objects of derived types and JSON serializer

Tags: c#, serialization

In my application I have an abstract class `Block` which is a superclass for two concrete classes: `OperationBlock` and `DecisionBlock`.

```
abstract class Block
    {
        public abstract void Draw(Graphics graphics);
    }
```

For the sake of an example, here's a part of the `DecisionBlock` class:

```
class DecisionBlock : Block
    {
        [JsonInclude] private int x;
        [JsonInclude] private int y;
        [JsonInclude] private Point[] vertices;
        public DecisionBlock(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            vertices = new Point[]
            {
                new Point(x, y),
                new Point(x + 50, y + 50),
                new Point(x + 100, y),
                new Point(x + 50, y - 50)
            };
        }
        // Draw() method, etc ...
    }
```

I store the `Block` objects in a list `List<Block> blocksList`. At one point, I want to save all the data about `Block`s in a file. The method responsible for saving the list to a file looks like that:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IncludeFields = true,
};
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(blocksList, options);
File.WriteAllText("save.dat", jsonString);
```

After instantiating three `Block` objects, adding them to the list, and calling the above method, the contents of the `save.dat` file are

```
[{},{},{}]
```

(i.e. all the fields are apparently invisible to the serializer). I suspect that the serializer cannot handle polymorphism properly and what *really* gets serialized is the abstract `Block` class. Is there any way to fix this? Or do I have to forsake using JSON serialization altogether and save everything manually?

Comment: You should use  `JsonProperty` for the private fields, see the answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010248/1360389).

Comment: @GellioGao that answer is for JSON.Net, this question is about System.Text.Json

Comment: In System.Text.Json it looks like [Support polymorphic deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#support-polymorphic-deserialization) is required to handle subclasses. Much easier in Json.NET using [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) but I expect System.Text.Json will catch up eventually. (NOTE: **never** use TypeNameHandling when consuming Json from an untrusted source!)

Comment: @stuartd oh, my bad. So, check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869986/1360389) to use custom converters.

Comment: @GellioGao nice! Looks like a `JsonConverter<>` is required in both cases!

Comment: Incidentally, the docs I linked to above link back to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074304/is-polymorphic-deserialization-possible-in-system-text-json/59744873#59744873), so it looks like this question is a duplicate of that one.