# System.Text.Json Ignore JsonIgnore attribute when (De-)Serializing

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

I have just recently switched over from Json.Net (Newtonsoft) to System.Text.Json.

One of my classes which has a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on a property must be (de-)serialized with this property.

With Json.Net, we had a [ContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) which did the job (to ignore the `JsonIgnore` attribute).

How can we do this (ignore `[JsonIgnore]`) in the System.Text.Json context?

Answer (score 0):

In **[.NET 7 and later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#contract-customization)** Microsoft has added the ability to programmatically customize the [serialization contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts) that System.Text.Json creates for each .NET type.  This functionality corresponds to Json.NET's [contract customization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) capability. Using this functionality you can add a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to unignore selected properties of selected types.

First, create the following extension class with [`JsonTypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinfo?view=net-7.0) modifier actions:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> UnignoreProperties(Type type, params string [] properties) => 
        typeInfo => 
        {
            if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type) && typeInfo.Kind == JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                // [JsonIgnore] is implemented by setting ShouldSerialize to a function that returns false.
                foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties.Where(p => ShouldUnignore(p, properties)))
                {
                    property.Get ??= CreatePropertyGetter(property);
                    property.Set ??= CreatePropertySetter(property);
                    if (property.Get != null)
                        property.ShouldSerialize = null;
                }
        };

    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> UnignorePropertiesForDeserialize(Type type, params string [] properties) => 
        typeInfo => 
        {
            if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type) && typeInfo.Kind == JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                // [JsonIgnore] is implemented by setting ShouldSerialize to a function that returns false.
                foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties.Where(p => ShouldUnignore(p, properties)))
                {
                    property.Set ??= CreatePropertySetter(property);
                }
        };

    static bool ShouldUnignore(JsonPropertyInfo property, string [] properties) => 
        property.ShouldSerialize != null && property.AttributeProvider?.IsDefined(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute), true) == true && properties.Contains(property.GetMemberName());
    
    // CreateGetter() and CreateSetter() taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76296944/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869393/get-net-core-jsonserializer-to-serialize-private-members
    
    delegate TValue RefFunc<TObject, TValue>(ref TObject arg);

    static Func<object, object?>? CreatePropertyGetter(JsonPropertyInfo property) =>
        property.GetPropertyInfo() is {} info && info.ReflectedType != null && info.GetGetMethod() is {} getMethod
        ? CreateGetter(info.ReflectedType, getMethod) : null;
    
    static Func<object, object?>? CreateGetter(Type type, MethodInfo? method)
    {
        if (method == null)
            return null;
        var myMethod = typeof(JsonExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(JsonExtensions.CreateGetterGeneric), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)!;
        return (Func<object, object?>)(myMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { type, method.ReturnType }).Invoke(null, new[] { method })!);
    }

    static Func<object, object?> CreateGetterGeneric<TObject, TValue>(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if(typeof(TObject).IsValueType)
        {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326736/how-can-i-create-an-open-delegate-from-a-structs-instance-method
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212346/uncurrying-an-instance-method-in-net/1212396#1212396
            var func = (RefFunc<TObject, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RefFunc<TObject, TValue>), null, method);
            return (o) => {var tObj = (TObject)o; return func(ref tObj); };
        }
        else
        {
            var func = (Func<TObject, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TObject, TValue>), method);
            return (o) => func((TObject)o);
        }
    }

    static Action<object,object?>? CreatePropertySetter(JsonPropertyInfo property) =>
        property.GetPropertyInfo() is {} info && info.ReflectedType != null && info.GetSetMethod() is {} setMethod
        ? CreateSetter(info.ReflectedType, setMethod) : null;

    static Action<object,object?>? CreateSetter(Type type, MethodInfo? method)
    {
        if (method == null)
            return null;
        var myMethod = typeof(JsonExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(JsonExtensions.CreateSetterGeneric), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)!;
        return (Action<object,object?>)(myMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new [] { type, method.GetParameters().Single().ParameterType }).Invoke(null, new[] { method })!);
    }

    static Action<object,object?>? CreateSetterGeneric<TObject, TValue>(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (typeof(TObject).IsValueType)
        {
            // TODO: find a performant way to do this.  Possibilities:
            // Box<T> from Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937935/how-to-mutate-a-boxed-struct-using-il
            return (o, v) => method.Invoke(o, new [] { v });
        }
        else
        {
            var func = (Action<TObject, TValue?>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TObject, TValue?>), method);
            return (o, v) => func((TObject)o, (TValue?)v);
        }
    }

    static PropertyInfo? GetPropertyInfo(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as PropertyInfo);
    static string? GetMemberName(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo)?.Name;
}
```

Now let's say your type looks like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string IgnoreMe { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int AlsoIgnoreMe { get; set; }
}
```

If you would like to **round-trip** your ignored properties, use `JsonExtensions.UnignoreProperties()`:

```
var myClass = new MyClass { IgnoreMe = "I Should Appear", AlsoIgnoreMe = 101 };

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.UnignoreProperties(typeof(MyClass), 
                                                        nameof(MyClass.IgnoreMe), nameof(MyClass.AlsoIgnoreMe)) },
    },
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myClass, options);

var myClass2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json, options);
```

But if you would only like to **deserialize** your ignored properties, use `JsonExtensions.UnignorePropertiesForDeserialize()`:

```
var json = 
    """
    {"IgnoreMe":"I Should Appear","AlsoIgnoreMe":101}
    """;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.UnignorePropertiesForDeserialize(typeof(MyClass), 
                                                                      nameof(MyClass.IgnoreMe), nameof(MyClass.AlsoIgnoreMe)) },
    },
};

var myClass2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json, options);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bO0RI6).

Comment: Can you change Default and Null behavior here?

Comment: @IgorBe - It should be possible, you would need to replace the value of [`JsonPropertyInfo.ShouldSerialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpropertyinfo.shouldserialize?view=net-8.0#remarks).  According to the docs, *For contracts originating from `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver`, the value of `Condition` will map to this predicate.*